# PDF Signing: PKCS11_get_private_key returned NULL

Tags: openssl, smartcard, pkcs#11

In Ubuntu 18.04.1, `openssl engine pkcs11 -t -c` properly shows

```
(pkcs11) pkcs11 engine
 [RSA, rsaEncryption, id-ecPublicKey]
     [ available ]
```

The purpose is to certify PDFs using the Safenet Token (Gemalto 5110) loaded with an [AATL](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list2.html) chained cert in slot 0:

```
$ pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so --login -O
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
Logging in to "pdfsigner".
Please enter User PIN:
Private Key Object; RSA
  label:
  ID:         hexstringblah
  Usage:      decrypt, sign, unwrap
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      te-123456-123456aa
  ID:         hexstringblah
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:

$ pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so --list-slots
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x0): AKS ifdh [eToken 5110 SC] 00 00
  token label        : pdfsigner
  token manufacturer : SafeNet, Inc.
  token model        : eToken
  token flags        : login required, rng, token initialized, PIN initialized, other flags=0x200
  hardware version   : 16.0
  firmware version   : 16.1
  serial num         : 123456
  pin min/max        : 6/20
```

When I try to sign with `openssl pkeyutl -sign -keyform ENGINE -engine pkcs11 -inkey "pkcs11:object=te-123456-123456aa;type=cert;pin-value=password" -in certifyme.pdf -out certifyme.pdf` I am getting

```
engine "pkcs11" set.
No private keys found.
PKCS11_get_private_key returned NULL
cannot load Private Key from engine
139808273490368:error:80067065:pkcs11 engine:ctx_load_privkey:object not found:eng_back.c:876:
139808273490368:error:26096080:engine routines:ENGINE_load_private_key:failed loading private key:../crypto/engine/eng_pkey.c:78:
unable to load Private Key
pkeyutl: Error initializing context
```

There is a private key in the token:

```
$ pkcs11-dump dump /usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so 0 password
pkcs11-dump 0.3.4 - PKI Cryptoki token dump
Written by Alon Bar-Lev

Copyright (C) 2005-2006 Alon Bar-Lev.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Token Information:
                         label: pdfsigner
                manufacturerID: SafeNet, Inc.
                         model: eToken
                  serialNumber: 123456
                         flags: CKF_RNG,CKF_LOGIN_REQUIRED,CKF_USER_PIN_INITIALIZED,CKF_DUAL_CRYPTO_OPERATIONS,CKF_TOKEN_INITIALIZED
             ulMaxSessionCount: 0
             ulMaxSessionCount: 0
                   ulMaxPinLen: 20
                   ulMinPinLen: 6
           ulTotalPublicMemory: 81920
            ulFreePublicMemory: 32767
          ulTotalPrivateMemory: 81920
           ulFreePrivateMemory: 32767
               hardwareVersion: 016.000
               firmwareVersion: 016.001
                       utcTime: \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 Object 0
                   Object size: 65
                     CKA_CLASS: CKO_PRIVATE_KEY
                     CKA_TOKEN: TRUE
                   CKA_PRIVATE: TRUE
                     CKA_LABEL:
                  CKA_KEY_TYPE: CKK_RSA
                   CKA_SUBJECT: ERROR

                        CKA_ID: 7c 14 f6 86 13 6b 31 9e

                 CKA_SENSITIVE: TRUE
                   CKA_DECRYPT: TRUE
                    CKA_UNWRAP: TRUE
                      CKA_SIGN: TRUE
              CKA_SIGN_RECOVER: TRUE
                    CKA_DERIVE: FALSE
                CKA_START_DATE:
                  CKA_END_DATE:
                   CKA_MODULUS:

$ p11tool --provider=/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so --list-all
    Object 0:
            URL: pkcs11:model=eToken;manufacturer=MFG.;serial=123456;token=pdfsigner;id=00escapedhex;object=te-123456-123456aa;type=cert
            Type: X.509 Certificate
            Label: te-123456-123456aa
            ID: 00escapedhex

    Object 1:
            URL: pkcs11:model=eToken;manufacturer=MFG.;serial=123456;token=pdfsigner;type=cert
            Type: X.509 Certificate
            Label:
            Flags: CKA_CERTIFICATE_CATEGORY=CA;
            ID:

    Object 2:
            URL: pkcs11:model=eToken;manufacturer=MFG.;serial=123456;token=pdfsigner;type=cert
            Type: X.509 Certificate
            Label:
            Flags: CKA_CERTIFICATE_CATEGORY=CA;
            ID:

    Object 3:
            URL: pkcs11:model=eToken;manufacturer=MFG.;serial=123456;token=pdfsigner;type=cert
            Type: X.509 Certificate
            Label:
            Flags: CKA_CERTIFICATE_CATEGORY=CA;
            ID:

    Object 4:
            URL: pkcs11:model=eToken;manufacturer=MFG.;serial=123456;token=pdfsigner;type=cert
            Type: X.509 Certificate
            Label:
            Flags: CKA_CERTIFICATE_CATEGORY=CA;
            ID:
```

AFAIK the cmd should not request the PK, but only to have the token sign the request. Do I have an incorrect parameter in pkeyutl?

I was able to use the same token to certify and sign a PDF in Windows. **How do I sign the PDF via PKCS#11 and openssl?**

Comment: Beware that you don't need to retrieve the private key. In fact, the eToken is meant to disallow its extraction. You can list the stored private keys' IDs and then choose one to sign your file, buy it is the eToken itself who calculates the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have one RSA private key object and multiple certificate objects in your PKCS11 object store.
But you are trying to use your Certificate to sign your "certifyme.pdf" file. From your command it shows that the object "te-123456-123456aa" (CKA_LABEL) is a certificate.

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -keyform ENGINE -engine pkcs11 -inkey "pkcs11:object=te-123456-123456aa;type=cert;pin-value=password" -in certifyme.pdf -out certifyme.pdf

Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      te-123456-123456aa
  ID:         hexstringblah
```

Instead you can use your RSA private key id (CKA_ID, as you don't have a label for your private key) to sign your pdf file.

```
Private Key Object; RSA
  label:
  ID:         hexstringblah
  Usage:      decrypt, sign, unwrap

openssl pkeyutl -sign -keyform ENGINE -engine pkcs11 -inkey "pkcs11:id=hexstringblah;type=private;pin-value=password" -in certifyme.pdf -out signed_certifyme.pdf
```

Also note that in your command input file and ouput files has the same name.

Hope this helps.